# Will use of a kernel object in C# flush CPU cache?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, .net-4.0, .net-4.5

If I have a code similar to this:

```
ManualResetEvent me = new ManualResetEvent(false);
. . .
int a = 10;
. . .
me.WaitOne();
. . .
```

assume `a` is in the CPU cache after the assignment, *will call to WaitOne flush it to the RAM?*

Or (more importantly)

**will an access to a kernel sync object (like WaitHangle) from .NET result in CPU cache flush / memory barrier?**

Or

**does switch to kernel mode require memory barrier?**

Comment: Interesting question, but: it probably depends on *what is `a`* - because in the example given, the compiler will typically remove it as an unused variable - and even if it was used, since no other threads can see it (as a register/stack value) it is hard to answer meaningfully. Would probably need to be a field to be a concern.

Comment: @MarcGravell I have asked this 3 different ways to avoid being specific on 'a'. I need to know will the CPU cache be flushed before switching to kernel mode (regardless the 'a' origin - there will be lot of stuff in the cache not just 'a' and not just from this thread or process.. right?)

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/681505/does-an-eventwaithandle-have-any-implicit-memorybarrier, in particular this answer: http://stackoverflow.com/a/10651601/23354

Comment: if you read the answer - there is a lot of 'I think' and contradictions (like he is saying Richter said yes and I think no etc).. Plus it is very specific to the calling method Set on the specific WaitHandle... (hence the answer applies to the implementation of a piece of code)... my question is - generally speaking is there a link between switching .NET app to kernel-mode and ensuring CPU cache coherency

Comment: Possibly answered here: http://igoro.com/archive/volatile-keyword-in-c-memory-model-explained. WaitOne has acquire semantics, so cache will be refreshed but not flushed

Comment: finally. someone who knows something about the topic and not fishing for the SO score! perhaps in 15 yrs time this will be place for intelligent exchange of knowledge and NOT a horse races betting for nerds..

Comment: Are you looking for "might my variable be flushed to memory?" or "can I guarantee that my variable will be flushed to memory?"  And are you looking at "Microsoft's .NET on x86," or .NET in general on any platform with potentially emulated kernel calls?

Comment: I am looking at x64.. I didn't know that changes behavior. whats `emulated kernel calls` ?