# Writing data with locks, but reading without a lock

Tags: c#

If i write data using many threads into a property e.g:
public decimal number;

will using volatile decimal allow me to read the decimal exception safe without using a lock?

Comment: No. Read these: [Part 1](https://web.archive.org/web/20161225050237/http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/12/can-skip-lock-reading-integer) [Part 2](https://web.archive.org/web/20160729162225/http://blog.coverity.com/2014/03/26/reordering-optimizations/). Never use `volatile` (unless you work at Microsoft, but a good number of C# language *designers* say they're not comfortable enough with volatile's semantics to use it). Also, tearing.

Comment: Since you're writing to it using a lock why not just use a lock to read from it?

Comment: [This answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1668984) for the marked duplicate addresses _exactly_ your question, directly and clearly.

Comment: @canton7: Thanks for the link. I need to move those to my blog.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A `decimal` can not be marked [`volatile`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/keywords/volatile). You will get a compiler error. The reason is that operations on this type can not be guaranteed to be atomic due to its size.

You can not assume that lock-free read will be safe. It may return a partially written value which may be invalid, and will definitely not be a desired value.

Comment: oh ok, so even other types that i could set as volatile still aren't safe to read from?

Comment: Other types should try to use the `Interlocked` class for reading and writing without `lock`s.

Comment: (note that you need to both read *and* write using `Interlocked` -- you can't use `Interlocked` just for writing, and ignore it for reading)

Comment: @Andyx: You need to clearly define what you mean by "safe to read from". What safety property are you interested in? `volatile` guarantees only a very small number of safety properties; it guarantees *atomicity* because only atomic types may be marked as volatile, and it guarantees that reads will not be moved backwards in time with respect to certain other special effects; that is, it introduces a half fence. If you are not comfortable reasoning about fences then you should do what I do and not use `volatile`.