# AtomicXXX.get() equivalent

Tags: c#, multithreading, atomic, volatile, interlocked

In Java, `AtomicInteger` and `AtomicLong` seem to implement the same functionality as .NET's `Interlocked`. Additionally, they provide a `get()` method to read the most current value (which may differ from that stored in the CPU cache):

```
    private volatile int value;

    // ...

    /**
     * Gets the current value.
     *
     * @return the current value
     */
    public final int get() {
        return value;
    }
```

On the other hand, `Interlocked` only provides a [`Read(...)`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked.read%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) method for 64-bit values, which only guarantees they're read *consistently* (i.e. on 32-bit system you don't read any garbage), but not that the value read is the *most current* one.

Now the question. If I use a `volatile` variable in conjunction with `Interlocked`, does it guarantee that the value can be both incremented/decremented *and* read/written *atomically*?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Does Interlocked guarantee visibility to other threads in C# or do I still have to use volatile?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2475222/does-interlocked-guarantee-visibility-to-other-threads-in-c-sharp-or-do-i-still)

Comment: Indeed. This looks like the valid answer to my question. I wonder how comes I missed it earlier.