# Are basic arithmetic operations in C# atomic

Tags: c#, thread-safety, locking, arithmetic-expressions

Are the basic arithmetic operations Thread safe?

For example, if there is `++` operation on a global variable, which will be modified from different threads, is it necessary to a lock around it?

For example

```
void MyThread() // can have many running instances
{
    aGlobal++;
}
```

or should it be

```
void MyThread()
{
    lock( lockerObj)
    {
        aGlobal++;
    }
}
```

Comment: this ain't an exclusive arithmetic operation ... there's a write to a variable either! `a + a` is something different than `a = a + a`. you'd have to use `Interlocked.Increment` or alikes!

Answer (score 10, accepted):

[The spec](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms228593.aspx) sums it up very well. Section 5.5, "Atomicity of variable references":

> Reads and writes of the following data types are atomic: bool, char,
>   byte, sbyte, short, ushort, uint, int, float, and reference types. In
>   addition, reads and writes of enum types with an underlying type in
>   the previous list are also atomic. Reads and writes of other types,
>   including long, ulong, double, and decimal, as well as user-defined
>   types, are not guaranteed to be atomic. Aside from the library
>   functions designed for that purpose, there is no guarantee of atomic
>   read-modify-write, such as in the case of increment or decrement.

Conclusions:

- Independent reads/writes are atomic (but only for some data types)
- Read/modify/write (such as `i++`) is *never* atomic
- You can use the [`Interlocked`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Threading.Interlocked.aspx) class methods to achieve atomicity when it's not already guaranteed

In cases where `Interlocked` functionality is not enough there is no other option than to use a synchronization primitive, such as [`Monitor.Enter`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/de0542zz.aspx) (which the compiler also exposes through the `lock` statement).

Answer (score 2):

Reads and writes *independently* are atomic on most types (not the longer types, usually 64bit+). But what you want is to read, change, then write atomically - this is definitely **not** atomic.

If you need to increment a value, there is the `System.Threading.Interlocked` class with static `Increment` and `Decrement` actions.

If you need to do more complex sums, then synchronisation using `lock` or another construct is the only way. That or make things immutable as in messaging systems so you don't get any shared data access issues, but this usually isn't attainable unless designed for upfront.

Answer (score 0):

Neither ... you should go for `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment(ref int location)` instead. This is lock-free as it ensures that the processor executes the read and the write (instructions - which are atomic) in exactly the wanted order - whereas not using `System.Threading.Interlocked.Increment` offers the opportunity to the processor to reorder instructions.

Doing the sledgehammer (or having no other possiblity, as you may be doing a heavy amount of operations), you can also use `lock` - but even in these scenarios I would rather go for `System.Threading.ReaderWriterLockSlim` instead.

btw - [a nice read](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154551/volatile-vs-interlocked-vs-lock)!