# Should a lock variable be declared volatile?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, locking, volatile

I have the following Lock statement:

```
private readonly object ownerLock_ = new object();

lock (ownerLock_)
{
}
```

Should I use [volatile](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7(v=vs.71).aspx) keyword for my lock variable?

```
private readonly volatile object ownerLock_ = new object();
```

On MSDN I saw that it usually used for a field that is accessed without locking, so if I use Lock I don't need to use volatile?

From [MSDN](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/x13ttww7(v=vs.71).aspx):

> The volatile modifier is usually used for a field that is accessed by
>   multiple threads without using the lock statement to serialize access.

Comment: We need far more context than this to answer the question. Where does this lock exist in relation to the objects utilizing the lock?

Comment: It is definitely thread safe as it currently exists. No guarantee will be possible when you add code within the lock{} block.

Comment: You shouldn't need to lock a `readonly` object...in that it is `readonly`...

Comment: worth a read to explain the diferent behaviour & functionality of Lock vs. Volatile

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/154551/volatile-vs-interlocked-vs-lock

Comment: I think he intends to use it as the lock baton for that critical section.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

If you're *only* ever accessing the data that the lock "guards" while you own the lock, then yes - making those fields volatile is superfluous. You don't need to make the `ownerLock_` variable volatile either. (You haven't currently shown any actual code within the `lock` statement, which makes it hard to talk about in concrete terms - but I'm assuming you'd *actually* be reading/modifying some data within the `lock` statement.)

`volatile` should be *very* rarely used in application code. If you want lock-free access to a single variable, `Interlocked` is almost always simpler to reason about. If you want lock-free access beyond that, I would almost always start locking. (Or try to use immutable data structures to start with.)

I'd only expect to see `volatile` within code which is trying to build higher level abstractions for threading - so within the TPL codebase, for example. It's really a tool for experts who *really* understand the .NET memory model thoroughly... of whom there are very few, IMO.

Comment: Thanks for your quick reply, Lets say I'm using only Lock, it seems rare but can 2 threads that will come to the lock statement both will check ownerLock_ state at the same time and try to lock it or each other? I'm asking this question because I had problem with the locking in my code and I think it related to this issue.

Comment: @DorCohen: Only one of them will acquire the lock at a time. It will then execute the body of the `lock` statement, and when it releases the lock, the other thread will be able to acquire the lock and execute the code.

Comment: @DorCohen, it seems that your problem is not in what you're locking, but what you're attempting to do within the lock body.

Comment: @DorCohen - One thing to bear in mind with locks is that you lock on an *instance* of an object, not just a field. So you need to make sure that each thread that will attempt to acquire the lock will be given the same instance of the "guard" object.

This MSDN article has more information: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms173179(v=VS.80).aspx

Comment: If there was no "readonly" (but the lock itself was never actually written) would the answer still apply?  How about if the lock was writable and changing for some obscure case?

Comment: @crokusek: If the lock is writable, that's a problem in all kinds of ways. If it's not readonly, I *think* it would still be okay.

Answer (score 3):

If something is `readonly` it's thread-safe, period.  (Well, almost.  An expert *might* be able to figure out how to get a NullReferenceException on your `lock` statement, but it wouldn't be easy.)  With `readonly` you don't need `volatile`, `Interlocked`, or locking.  It's the ideal keyword for multi-threading, and you should use it where ever you can.  It works great for a lock object where its big disadvantage  (you can't change the value) doesn't matter.

Also, while the *reference* is immutable, the object referenced may not be.  "new object()" is here, but if it was a `List` or something else mutable--and not thread-safe--you *would* want to lock the reference (and all other references to it, if any) to keep the object from changing in two threads at once.