# Correct way to lock a DataTable in C# for multithreading?

Tags: c#, multithreading, datatable

Is this the correct way to lock and modify a `DataTable` that is shared by multiple threads? If not, what would be the correct way to do it?

```
private void DoGeocodeLookup(object info)
{
    ParameterRow data = (ParameterRow)info;
    DataRow dr = data.Dr;
    int localIndex = data.Index;
    ManualResetEvent doneEvent = data.m_doneEvent; 

    Geocode_Google.GeoCode gc = new GeoCode();

    gc.Addr_In = m_dtAddress.Rows[localIndex]["AddressStd_tx"].ToString();

    gc.GeoCodeOne();

    if (gc.Status == "OK")
    {
        //write back to temporary datatable
        lock( m_TempTable.Rows.SyncRoot )
        {
            m_TempTable.Rows[localIndex]["GL_Address"] = gc.Thoroughfare_tx; 
        }
    }
    doneEvent.Set(); 
}
```

My Structure:

```
struct ParameterRow
{
    private DataRow m_row;
    private int m_index;

    public DataRow Dr
    {
        get { return m_row; }
        set { m_row = value; }
    }

    public int Index
    {
        get { return m_index; }
        set { m_index = value; }
    }

    public ManualResetEvent m_doneEvent;

    public ParameterRow( DataRow row, int index, ManualResetEvent doneEvent)
    {
        m_row = row;
        m_index = index;
        m_doneEvent = doneEvent; 
    }
}
```

Snippet where I start all threads:

```
//make temporary table
m_TempTable = new DataTable();
m_TempTable = m_dtAddress.Copy();

for (int index = 0; index < m_geocodes; index++)
{
    doneEvents[index] = new ManualResetEvent(false);
    ThreadPool.QueueUserWorkItem(DoGeocodeLookup, new ParameterRow( m_dtAddress.Rows[index], index, doneEvents[index]));  
}

WaitHandle.WaitAll(doneEvents);
```

Comment: Looks like that could work but why not just make the DataTable volatile?

Comment: Is that the better way to go?

Comment: I think so. It ensues that each thread will get the most up to version.

Comment: Why are you creating a structure with DataTable, According to C# standard, a structure should be created of only primitive types. struct size should be less than 16 bytes

Comment: @Anon - Okay. I'll give that a try. I don't need to include the `lock` statement if I declare my `DataTable` as volatile then? 
@TheIndianProgrammmer - That's actually a good point, I think. I guess I don't need to pass the entire `DataRow` to the thread. I just need the the address components to build a URL to send off.

Comment: @d2jxp exactly. You should be good to go!

Comment: @Anon - marking the DataTable as volatile will not help at all.  The volative will only affect the reference stored in m_TempTable (that is if the m_TempTable where change to point to a different DataTable, each thread would see the change immediately).  It does not affect the internal state of any object, so would do nothing to protect any accesses or updates to m_TempTable.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your example does not require any locking of the `DataTable`.  Inside of `DoGeocodeLookup` you are only peforming reads of the `DataTable`.  The only access you are performing on the table is to look up a row, which counts as a read.  The [DataTable](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.datatable.aspx) class is marked as being safe for multi-threaded read operations.  If you where doing something like adding new rows in `DoGeocodeLookup` then you would require locking.

The only thing that you are changing is the data in a single `DataRow` specified by `localIndex`.  Since each call to `DoGeocodeLookup` uses a differnet row - a single row in your table will only ever be updated by one thread, so you do not have a synchronization issue there.  So that will require no locking either.

Answer (score 0):

This [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154551/volatile-vs-interlocked-vs-lock) is very informative and may help with your question.  The general consensus is to use Interlock.Increment(object to be updated).  Locking is slow, and you have to remember any and all the places you may have locked the object you are updating.  And volatile doesn't necessarily mean that CPU A would see what CPU B just changed right away.