# Making threads fails after a while

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading

I wrote a code which uses threads in a Linux C++ program. But it fails after a while, I  don't know why. I think there may be a memory leakage somewhere. This is a simplified version:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;


#define MAX_THREADS  20
#define THREAD_STACK  100000
pthread_t pid[MAX_THREADS];

unsigned thread_args[MAX_THREADS][2];
volatile unsigned thread_number = 0;

void* TaskCode(void* parg)
{
    unsigned a = ((unsigned *)parg)[0];
    unsigned b = ((unsigned *)parg)[1];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        ;
    cout<< "\n\n" << a << "  " << b << "\n\n";

    thread_number--;
    return 0;
}

void Action(unsigned long a,unsigned b)
{
    if(thread_number >= MAX_THREADS)
        return;
    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREAD_STACK);
    thread_args[thread_number][0] = a;
    thread_args[thread_number][1] = b;
    if(pthread_create(&pid[thread_number],&attrs, TaskCode, (void*) thread_args[thread_number]) != 0)
    {
        cout<< "\n\n" "new thread failed. thread number:" << thread_number << "\n\n";
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < thread_number; i++)
            pthread_kill(pid[i], SIGSTOP);
    }
    thread_number++;
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    while(true)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            ;
        Action(time(0),1);
    }

    cout<< "\n\nunexpected end\n\n";
}
```

What's wrong with it?

---

**Edit:**
As suggested I changed the code:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;

#define MAX_THREADS  20
#define THREAD_STACK  100000
pthread_t pid[MAX_THREADS];

unsigned thread_args[MAX_THREADS][2];
volatile unsigned thread_number = 0;

pthread_mutex_t mutex_;

void* TaskCode(void* parg)
{
    unsigned a = ((unsigned *)parg)[0];
    unsigned b = ((unsigned *)parg)[1];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        ;
    cout<< "\n\n" << a << "  " << b << "\n\n";
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    thread_number--;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
    return 0;
}

void Action(unsigned long a,unsigned b)
{
    if(thread_number >= MAX_THREADS)
        return;
    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREAD_STACK);
    thread_args[thread_number][0] = a;
    thread_args[thread_number][1] = b;
    if(pthread_create(&pid[thread_number],&attrs, TaskCode, (void*) thread_args[thread_number]) != 0)
    {
        cout<< "\n\n" "new thread failed. thread number:" << thread_number << "\n\n";
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < thread_number; i++)
            pthread_kill(pid[i], SIGSTOP);
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    thread_number++;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
}

int main()
{
    int a = 0;
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_, NULL);
    while(true)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            ;
        Action(time(0),1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_);
    cout<< "\n\nunexpected endn\n";
}
```

Still it fails.

Comment: Where exactly does it fail? What's the error message do you get?

Comment: just `pthread_create` keeps returning nonzero after a few seconds; for the code above.

Comment: interesting how you always reuse the low-numbered thread slots early.

Comment: Any reason you give each thread 100000Byte stack address space? 4KB should suffice, not that it really matters...

Comment: @Deduplicator: just to be sure it suffices.bt the changing it will not prevent failure.

Comment: Your main thread is not cleaning up after the threads are killed. If the threads are joinable, join them so their resources can be cleaned up. Alternatively, create detached threads if possible so automatic cleanup will occur.

Comment: @alvits How can I create detached threads?

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - `pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrs, PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED)` will set the attrs appropriately. Put this line after the `pthread_init(&attrs)`.

Comment: @alvits: thanks. It seems to be a solution. if that was not a comment I could accept it as an answer.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - I posted my answer. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

By default threads are created with detachstate set to joinable. This requires that threads be joined to get the return code of a thread and cleanup the resources used.

Without cleaning up you'll run out of memory really quickly (memory leak).

For cases where threads need not return any code and cleanup of memory can be done as soon as the thread exits, then detached threads can be created.

To set the attribute such that all threads created will be detached use `pthread_attr_setdetachstate()`. Set the value to `PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED`.

```
pthread_init(&attrs);
pthread_attr_setcreatedetached(&attrs,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
```

Answer (score 2):

Your program fails in one of two ways for me.

- You run out of memory.
- `thread_number` gets corrupted due to locking as noted by @acarlon.

If the program runs long enough (`thread_number` isn't corrupted), then you run out of memory due to spawning of threads.  You spawn threads very quickly.  You never `join` the threads after they exit.  Each thread continues to sit in memory until `pthread_join` is called so that you can recover it's return code.

To verify, print `errno` when `pthread_create` fails:

```
cout << "pthread_create failed:" << strerror(errno) << endl;
```

The above prints (if it executes long enough):

```
pthread_create failed: Cannot allocate memory
```

You will need to include `string.h` and `errno.h`.

The second failure case I noted is when `thread_number` gets corrupted.  You can verify this by printing `thread_number` in your `TaskCode`.  You will note that you sometimes get values outside of 0-20 (4294967295 for example).  This is the corruption noted by @acarlon.

Comment: if I add `pthread_join(pid[this_thread_number],0);` after calling `pthread_create`, making new threads working separately, becomes pointless!

Answer (score 1):

```
 volatile unsigned thread_number = 0;
```

Volatile on its own isn't safe you need to use interlocked increment and decrement or use a mutex around the thread_number. Volatile will guarantee that threads do not operate on local cached copies. So, if you write a value to a shared variable on one thread, the other threads will see the new value when they read it. However, it does not guarantee that operations occur atomically.

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/154803/746754) which is actually for C#, but has the right idea.

Comment: I changed my code (see my question), I'm not sure if this is exactly what you suggested.

Comment: @MinimusHeximus - Your new code looks fine regarding the locks. There was also the problem or running out of memory that esorton found.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to all answers and comments this is my final code, I add to archive:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <stdio.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <signal.h>

using namespace std;


#define MAX_THREADS  20
#define THREAD_STACK  100000
pthread_t pid[MAX_THREADS];


unsigned thread_args[MAX_THREADS][3];
volatile bool pid_flags[MAX_THREADS] = {0};// all false

pthread_mutex_t mutex_;

void* TaskCode(void* parg)
{
    unsigned a = ((unsigned *)parg)[0];
    unsigned b = ((unsigned *)parg)[1];
    unsigned index = ((unsigned*)parg)[2];

    for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
        ;
    cout<< "\n\n" << a << "  " << b << "\n\n";


    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    pid_flags[index] = false;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
    return 0;
}

void Sleep(unsigned milliseconds)
{
    usleep(milliseconds * 1000);
}

bool FreeIndex(unsigned& index)
{
    bool b;
    for(index = 0; index < MAX_THREADS; index++)
    {
        pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
        b = pid_flags[index];
        pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
        if(b == false)
            return true;
    }
    return false;
}

void Action(unsigned long a,unsigned b)
{
    pthread_attr_t  attrs;
    pthread_attr_init(&attrs);
    pthread_attr_setdetachstate(&attrs,PTHREAD_CREATE_DETACHED);
    pthread_attr_setstacksize(&attrs, THREAD_STACK);


    unsigned free_index;

    while(!FreeIndex(free_index))
        Sleep(50);

    thread_args[free_index][0] = a;
    thread_args[free_index][1] = b;
    thread_args[free_index][2] = free_index;
    if(pthread_create(&pid[free_index],&attrs, TaskCode, (void*) thread_args[free_index]) != 0)
    {
        cout<< "\n\n" "Threading failed." "\n\n";
        bool b;
        for(unsigned i = 0; i < MAX_THREADS; i++)
        {
            pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
            b = pid_flags[i];
            pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
            if(b == true)
                pthread_kill(pid[i], SIGSTOP);
        }
    }
    pthread_mutex_lock(&mutex_);
    pid_flags[free_index] = true;
    pthread_mutex_unlock(&mutex_);
}

int main()
{
    pthread_mutex_init(&mutex_,0);
    while(true)
    {
        for(int i = 0; i < 1000; i++)
            ;
        Action(time(0),1);
    }
    pthread_mutex_destroy(&mutex_);
    cout<< "\n\n" "unexpected end" "\n\n";
}
```

Any improvement comments is appreciated.