# How do I use Interlocked.Add() correctly?

Tags: c#, multithreading

From the documentation [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.interlocked(v=vs.110).aspx): "The methods of this class help protect against errors that can occur when the scheduler switches contexts while a thread is updating a variable that can be accessed by other threads..."

Also, an answer to [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/154551/volatile-vs-interlocked-vs-lock?utm_medium=organic&utm_source=google_rich_qa&utm_campaign=google_rich_qa) states "INTERLOCKED METHODS ARE CONCURRENTLY SAFE ON ANY NUMBER OF COREs OR CPUs" which seems pretty clear.

Based on the above I thought Interlocked.Add() would be sufficient for multiple threads to do addition on a variable.  Apparently I'm wrong or I'm using the method incorrectly.   In the runnable code below I expect Downloader.ActiveRequestCount to be zero when Run() completes.  If I do not lock around the call to Interlocked.Add I get a random non-zero result.  What is the correct usage of Interlocked.Add()?

```
class Program
{
    private Downloader downloader { get; set; }

    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        new Program().Run().Wait();
    }


    public async Task Run()
    {
        downloader = new Downloader();
        List<Task> tasks = new List<Task>(100);

        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            tasks.Add(Task.Run(Download));

        await Task.WhenAll(tasks);

        Console.Clear();
        //expected:0, actual when lock is not used:random number i.e. 51,115
        Console.WriteLine($"ActiveRequestCount is : {downloader.ActiveRequestCount}"); 
        Console.ReadLine();


    }

    private async Task Download()
    {
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++)
            await downloader.Download();
    }
}

public class Downloader :INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private object locker = new object();
    private int _ActiveRequestCount;
    public int ActiveRequestCount { get => _ActiveRequestCount; private set => _ActiveRequestCount = value; }

    public async Task<string> Download()
    {
        string result = string.Empty;

        try
        {
            IncrementActiveRequestCount(1);
            result = await Task.FromResult("boo");
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("oops");
        }
        finally
        {
            IncrementActiveRequestCount(-1);
        }

        return result;
    }


    public void IncrementActiveRequestCount(int value)
    {
        //lock (locker)       // is this redundant
        //{
            _ActiveRequestCount = Interlocked.Add(ref _ActiveRequestCount, value);
        //}

        RaisePropertyChanged(nameof(ActiveRequestCount));
    }

    #region INotifyPropertyChanged implementation
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;
    public void RaisePropertyChanged([CallerMemberNameAttribute] string propertyName = "") => PropertyChanged?.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    #endregion
}
```

Comment: You don't need to assign the result of Add back to the field. The field _ActiveRequestCount is incremented by the method, that's why it takes a ref.

Comment: OMG what was I thinking.  Thanks mike.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace

```
_ActiveRequestCount = Interlocked.Add(ref _ActiveRequestCount, value);
```

with

```
Interlocked.Add(ref _ActiveRequestCount, value);
```

Interlocked.Add is thread-safe and takes a `ref` parameter, so that it can do the assignment safely. You *additionally* perform an (unnecessary) unsafe assignment (`=`). Just remove it.